# Javascript file isn't running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 3 .js files like below...

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="newjavascript.js"></script>
```

all in the head category.

It appears that newjavascript.js isn't used at all when I run it from netbeans 7.3 with chrome integration. Is there a sequence the scripts should be in.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Also check browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: jquery should be your first reference and them the others.

Answer (score 3):

jquery should be included before jquery-ui - so swap 1 & 2 scripts

Also make sure the `newjavascript.js` is not giving an 404 error - check the browser developer tool's network tab for this

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="newjavascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [Jquery UI](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/) page.

Jquery UI is depending on Jquery. You should include Jquery before Jquery UI.